# The return type 'List<dynamic>' isn't a 'FutureOr<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>', as required by the closure's context Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wrote this code in older version of flutter, I think 1.8, but now I'm getting this error. How can I remove it. Here is the code -

```
getProviders(parentTicketId) async {
    List<Map> orders = await _firestore
        .collection('orders')
        .where('parent_ticketId', isEqualTo: parentTicketId)
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.docs)
        .then((value) =>
            value.map((e) => {'id': e.id, ...e.data}).toList());  //This line is giving the error.

    List<Map> providers = [];
    for (var order in orders) {
      providers.add(await _firestore
          .collection('providers')
          .doc(order['provider_id'])
          .get()
          .then((provider) => {
                 //TODO: Check
                'name': provider.get('name'),
                //'name': provider.data['name'],
                'phone': provider.get('phone'),
                //'phone': provider.data['phone'],
                'order_ticketId': order['ticketId'],
                'order_id': order['id'],
                'id': provider.id,
              }));
    }
```

Comment: i can't find any return here, I think you forgot to add ` return providers`. Does it solve the errors?

Comment: `return` not needed with the `() => something` notation. the something will be returned, in this case the Map `{'name': ....etc}`

Answer (score 1):

> value.map((e) => {'id': e.id, ...e.data}).toList());

Here, you can not directly access `id` with `e.id`.
You should rather use `e.data().id`.

using `fromJson` or something similar like that is recommanded.